# springboot RestApi file/image upload, consuming with RESTeasy

Tags: java, file-upload, multipartform-data, resteasy

I am trying to consume a Springboot File upload api, that takes in a MultipartFile... via RESTeasy    with packages resteasy-client:3.9.1.final && resteasy-multipart-provider:3.9.1.final.

However i am failing to get the implementation right. Any Suggestions

Here's an example of how the code looks like

`WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("url");
MultipartFormDataOutput formData = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
byte[] fileContent = request.getContent().getBytes[];

formData.addFormData("image", new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
Entity entity = Entity.entity(formData,
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
Response response = target.request().post(entity);`

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Can you upgrade RESTEasy? That's a very old unsupported version.

Comment: Upgrading the RESTEasy, would mean that i would need to change a whole lot of api calls since this was legacy application...therefore not a viable option

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix for the above,

`MultipartFormData formdata = new MultipartFormData(); formData.addFormData("file", new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(), MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE, fileName, true); Entity<MultiPartFormDataOutput> entity = Entity.entity(formData, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);`

Then post with entity